# How do I filter an output of an AJAX call in Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I've succesfully set up a Datatables plugin, created a new table and filled it with content using an AJAX call:

```
var table= $("#mytable").DataTable({

    ajax: "list.json",
    columns: [
        {"data": "name"},
        {"data": "location"},
        {"data": "date"}
    ]
});
```

The example above has output all of the items from the JSON file I am importing.

What I want is to *filter the output*, e.g. fill the table with only the data of those users, whose location is "England".

Datatables is an extremely powerful plugin, so I got lost on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Or is it better to render a filtered JSON file on the server side?

Comment: You could use [filter](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()#Examples) api for DataTable, If you're using legacy datatables, you can use [fnFilter](http://legacy.datatables.net/api#fnFilter) api. Basically, if you're rendering small amount of data, it would be nice to use plugin features for sorting / searching / filtering on the fly on client side and doesn't make sense to go on the server side to get location specific users every time location changes. But if you're returning thousands of users, it would be nice to use server filtering as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks jeetaz! I will give it a shot.

Comment: @jeetaz, that's incorrect. `filter()` API method doesn't update the appearance of the table. From the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter%28%29): *This method should not be confused with `search()` which is used to search for records in the DataTable*

Comment: @Gyrocode.com you're right, the DataTable.filter api returns the array items which passes the filter test and it doesn't update DataTable. However, with legacy dataTable.[fnFilter](http://legacy.datatables.net/api#fnFilter) it is still a valid scenario and `oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();
oTable.fnFilter("^England$", 3, true);` could have updated table with expected results and which is similar to.DataTable.search() api.  But, thanks for clarification on DataTable.filter()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Filter the data on the server-side if you're not planning to show locations other than "England"
- Manipulate data received via Ajax using either [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option or [`xhr`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr) event
- Use [`search`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search%28%29) or [`searchCols`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchCols) options to define initial search, either globally or for specific column:

  ```
  var table= $("#mytable").DataTable({
     ajax: "list.json",
     columns: [
        {"data": "name"},
        {"data": "location"},
        {"data": "date"}
     ],
     searchCols: [
        null,
        { "search": "England" },
        null
     ]
  });
  ```

  See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmq6vko0/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Quick question, what if I my column has eithther <i class="fa fa-star"></i> or <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>. Is it possible to search thru this kind of data?

Comment: @Deka87, corrected code in my answer. I think it will work just fine, see https://jsfiddle.net/fmq6vko0/